# passing grunt parameters from one task to another

Tags: asynchronous, configuration, dependencies, gruntjs

I'm trying to pass the configuration values returned from the server(zookeeper) into compass (cdnHost, environment, etc) and seem to be having a hard time using the right approach.

I looked at ways to pass around args from one task to another on this page as a starting point

http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#how-can-i-share-parameters-across-multiple-tasks

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        compass: {
            dist: {
                //options: grunt.option('foo')
                //options: global.bar
                options: grunt.config.get('baz')
            }
        },

    ...

    grunt.registerTask('compassWithConfig', 'Run compass with external async config loaded first', function () {
        var done = this.async();
        someZookeeperConfig( function () {
            // some global.CONFIG object from zookeeper
            var config = CONFIG;
            // try grunt.option
            grunt.option('foo', config);
            // try config setting
            grunt.config.set('bar', config);
            // try global
            global['baz'] = config;
            done(true);
        });
    });

    ...

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'compassWithConfig', 'compass']);
```

I also tried calling the compass task directly, and it made no difference.

```
grunt.task.run('compass');
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. (e.g. way to use initConfig and have the value be available).

Thanks

Comment: I added a 'test' task to see if any of the values were being picked up, and they all were reading properly.


    `grunt.registerTask('test', function () {`

    `    console.log('test1', grunt.option('foo'));`

    `    console.log('test2', global.bar);`

    `    console.log('test3', grunt.config.get('baz'));`

    `});`


It must a different way to pass the value as an arg into compass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    compass: {
        dist: {
            options: grunt.config.get('baz')
        }
    }
```

... `grunt.config` is called right away, and returns the value of `baz` as it is *right now*. Altering it (later) in another task simply won't get picked-up.

How to solve that?

**#1: update compass.dist.options instead of updating baz**

```
grunt.registerTask('compassWithConfig', 'Run compass with external async config loaded first', function () {
    var done = this.async();
    someZookeeperConfig( function () {
        // some global.CONFIG object from zookeeper
        var config = CONFIG;
        grunt.config.set('compass.dist.options', config);
        done();
    });
});
```

Now, running task `compassWithConfig` first, then task `compass` will get the result you expect.

**#2: wrap-up compass task execution in order to abstract away config mapping**

```
grunt.registerTask('wrappedCompass', '', function () {
    grunt.config.set('compass.dist.options', grunt.config.get('baz'));
    grunt.task.run('compass');
});

// Then, you can manipulate 'baz' without knowing how it needs to be mapped for compass

grunt.registerTask('globalConfigurator', '', function () {
    var done = this.async();
    someZookeeperConfig( function () {
        // some global.CONFIG object from zookeeper
        var config = CONFIG;
        grunt.config.set('baz', config);
        done();
    });
});
```

Finally, running task `globalConfigurator` then `wrappedCompass` will get you to the result.

Comment: Ended up using #1. Thanks!